# ¿Como retornar el resultado de una consulta a BD con una función PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

quisiera saber como **retornar los valores** de una consulta a la base de datos **mediante una función PHP**, esto para tener disponible el ARRAY de datos en otros archivos y recorrerlo. Otra duda que me surge es como obtendría ese **return** de la **funcion PHP en Ajax**, ya que con eso pinto una pagina en especifico.

Intento de función que no me retorna nada.

```js
include "../conexion/conexionOra.php";
/***************************************************************************************************************/
function response(){
    
    if(isset($_POST['searchOption'])){
    $ident = $_POST['searchOption'];

        $stid6 = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM PLANEA.DOM WHERE CURP='$ident'");
        oci_execute($stid6);
        //ARREGLO INSTANCEADO DONDE GUARDARA EL ARREGLO DE OBJETOS DEL WHILE
        $dataIdent= array();
        //RECORRE LA CONSULTA E INSERTA EN UNA VARIABLE EN FORMA DE OBJETOS
        while (($row6 = oci_fetch_object($stid6)) != false) {
            $dataIdent[]= $row6;
        }
        if(count($dataIdent)>0){
          return $dataIdent;
          
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax que en caso de encontrar el dato en la BD pinta una pagina, de lo contrario pinto otra.

```js
$('#sendOption').on('submit',function (ev) {
  $('#mesageResult').html('<span></span>');
    $.ajax({
      type: $('#sendOption').attr('method'), 
      url: $('#sendOption').attr('action'),
      data: $('#sendOption').serialize(),
      success: function (data) { 
          //alert(data);
          //console.log(data);
          if(data){
            var contenedor = document.getElementById('container-center');
            contenedor.style.display='flex';
            $(contenedor).load('../pages/formResultUpdate.php');
            $('#messageResult').html('<span id=""></span>');
          }else{
            var contenedor = document.getElementById('container-center');
            contenedor.style.display='flex';
            $(contenedor).load('../pages/formNewRegistry.php');
            $('#messageResult').html('<span id="">No se encontraron datos, verifique el identificador o registrelo.</span>');
          }
        } 
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: He eliminado mi respuesta, pues debería ser mucho más amplia de lo que era para darte una buena respuesta a lo que pides. A cambio te paso unos enlaces donde lo podrás estudiar mejor: [Tipos de datos de retorno de la función ajax() de jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types), [ejemplo con json y array completo](https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso)

Comment: Solo necesito saber como tener disponibles los datos de esa consulta para otros scripts, tengo entendido que con funciones al retornar la variable que almacena los datos. Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Mïrate el enlace del ejemplo que te he dado, la parte final lo explica bastante bien, y ya tendrás una idea de como funciona realmente.  Básicamente los datos desde PHP no envian a ajax con un RETURN sino con `echo`, en el formato o tipo de datos que necesites y hayas preparado desde ajax. Hay miles de ejemplos por la red, no te hace falta una respuesta aquí, la verdad, pues la diversidad de métodos posibles (tipos de datos y manejo de los retornos) es muy grande y configurable.  Insisto, no busques una respuesta única,mira lo dicho en mi anterior comentario, y tendras un buen punto de partida